# WPF and C#: Accessing, referencing and setting value to control properties from other class

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, class, mainwindow

A really simple setup - Visual Studio 2010's default new WPF project, with MainWindow and App classes and XAML. On MainWindow there's only a simple control, a texbox, let's call it TB.
All I'm trying to do is access, read and modify TB's properties from another class, such as App.
That's all the code I have written, still, no can do.
I prefer not to assign the values from TB's properties to variables, but manage them directly.

Comment: U can do this only when ur class that is managing TB properties has reference to ur MainWindow or directly to TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class in which you want to modify the TB, store the TB's reference in that class. Then using that reference you can modify the properties of TB.

do something like this..

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        Textbox m_TextBox;

        public MyClass(Textbox TB)
        {
        m_TextBox = TB;
        }

        ModifyTextbox()
        {
           m_TextBox.Text = "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

in the MainWindow.cs create a new instance of MyClass

```
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass(TB);
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't get it. MainWindow is a class, and there's no instance of it in the project.

Comment: When you run your WPF application its the instance of MainWindow that is running.

Comment: OK... So what's the instance name?

Comment: you can get the instance of MainWindow using this code `Application.Current.MainWindow`

Comment: Try to follow a basic end to end tutorial on a simple WPF Application.

Comment: Thanks for all your patience. Off to the books.